# Syntax Error in Stored procedure while merging data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am trying to bulk copy functionality, using XML data, but it gives me a syntax error at merge statement. Please help me to rectify error

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[Matrices1D_PhysicalUnit_InsertXML]
    (@XmlData varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @idoc int  

    declare @tbl_Matrix1D_Dummy as table   
    (  
    MatricesPhysicalUnit1DPK  int,
    UNIT_CODE int,
    CHILDN int,
    SUCCEDN int,
    PRECEDN int,
    PROJECT int,
    WAUN int,
    MPARENT int
    )  

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @XmlData; --- Prepare XML Document   

    insert into @tbl_Matrix1D_Dummy 
    (MatricesPhysicalUnit1DPK  ,
    UNIT_CODE ,
    CHILDN ,
    SUCCEDN ,
    PRECEDN ,
    PROJECT ,
    WAUN ,
    MPARENT )
    (SELECT  MatricesPhysicalUnit1DPK,UNIT_CODE ,CHILDN,SUCCEDN,PRECEDN,PROJECT,WAUN,MPARENT   
    FROM OPENXML (@idoc,'//dsWSC//WBTSpecialCourse',2)  
    with (MatricesPhysicalUnit1DPK  int,
    UNIT_CODE int,
    CHILDN int,
    SUCCEDN int,
    PRECEDN int,
    PROJECT int,
    WAUN int,
    MPARENT int))

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc   --- Remove XML Document  
    select * from @tbl_Matrix1D_Dummy;
    MERGE into tbl_Matrix1D_PhyUnitOriginal as TargetTab
    using @tbl_Matrix1D_Dummy as SourceTab
    on TargetTab.MatricesPhysicalUnit1DPK=SourceTab.MatricesPhysicalUnit1DPK
    when matched then
    update  set
    TargetTab.UNIT_CODE=SourceTab.UNIT_CODE,
    TargetTab.CHILDN=SourceTab.CHILDN,
    TargetTab.SUCCEDN=SourceTab.SUCCEDN ,
    TargetTab.PRECEDN=SourceTab.PRECEDN,
    TargetTab.PROJECT=SourceTab.PROJECT,
    TargetTab.WAUN=SourceTab.WAUN,
    TargetTab.MPARENT=SourceTab.MPARENT
    when not matched then
    insert ( MatricesPhysicalUnit1DPK ,
    UNIT_CODE ,
    CHILDN ,
    SUCCEDN ,
    PRECEDN ,
    PROJECT ,
    WAUN ,
    MPARENT) values
    (
    SourceTab.MatricesPhysicalUnit1DPK ,
    SourceTab.UNIT_CODE ,
    SourceTab.CHILDN ,
    SourceTab.SUCCEDN ,
    SourceTab.PRECEDN ,
    SourceTab.PROJECT ,
    SourceTab.WAUN ,
    SourceTab.MPARENT
    );
    END
```

I am trying to copy bulk of data using XML data but it gives me syntax error at MERGE

> Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE'.

Comment: First off: which **version** of SQL Server are you using? `MERGE` is a new feature in SQL Server **2008** not available in 2005 or before. Also: if this is XML - why isn't the parameter of type `XML` ???

Comment: k.i am using SQL Server 2005.Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.tbl_Matrix1D_PhyUnitOriginal";
            try
            {
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dsMat1DPhy.Tables[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Actually there is no MERGE functionality in SQL Server 2005.
So this is another way for bulk copy and above stored procedure is also working in SQL server 2008.